# Select the last added node in TreeViewAdv

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treeview

Using Andrey Gliznetsov's [TreeViewAdv](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14741/Advanced-TreeView-for-NET), how do you add a node and then programmatically select it?

There is some useful information in [this document](http://trac.osgeo.org/mapguide/export/4865/sandbox/maestro-2.5/Thirdparty/TreeViewAdv/VBSample/Some%20Notes%20on%20using%20TreeViewAdv%20version%201_6_0_0.doc) but this section doesn't work for me

```
To select the tree item we need to find in which TreeView node represents our model node.
    _Model.Nodes.Add(n)
    Dim node As TreeNodeAdv = _Tree.FindNode(New TreePath(n))
    node.IsSelected = True
    _Tree.SelectedNode.ExpandAll()
    Tree.Select()
```

and the Syncfusion [page](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/treeview/faq/how-to-programmatically-select-a-node-in-a-treeviewadv) isn't helpful because you need a TreeViewAdv node but when you have just added it you only have a Aga.Controls.Tree.Node

```
'SelectedNode indicates the selected node of the TreeViewAdv. Select the first node under node 1.
    Me.treeViewAdv1.SelectedNode = Me.treeViewAdv1.Nodes(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Tree.FindNode but make sure the TreePath is formed correctly. Using New TreePath(n) does not give the right results but model.GetPath(n) does. Example of working code

```
    Dim n As Node = New ColumnNode(txtMessage.Text) 'ColumnNode class inherits Node and has public identifiers that correspond to NodeControl DataPropertyNames
    tvaTree.BeginUpdate()
    model.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(n)
    tvaTree.EndUpdate()

    'needs to be this construction using model.getpath(n). New TreePath(n) did not work!
    Dim tp As New TreePath()
    tp = model.GetPath(n)

    Dim lastnode As TreeNodeAdv = tvaTree.FindNode(tp)

    If lastnode IsNot Nothing Then
        tvaTree.ClearSelection()
        lastnode.IsSelected = True
        tvaTree.ScrollTo(lastnode)
    End If

    tvaTree.ExpandAll()
    tvaTree.Select() 'whole control needs to be selected to highlight the row
```

where model is a TreeMode object for the form and tvaTree is my treeviewadv control instance, and in the Form_Load method tvaTree.Model = model